# Am I comparing strings lexicographically correctly?

Tags: java, compareto, lexicographic

I am creating a method `compareTo(AltString altStr2)` that sorts strings by their length (shortest to longest).

However, I would like to go the extra mile and check for strings that are of the same length.  In that case, I figure it is best to sort the strings lexicographically, so that they are sorted in the same way they would appear in the dictionary.  So far my code is below.

```
public class AltString {

    String internalStr;

      public AltString(String str) {
        internalStr = str;
      }

      public String toString() {
        return internalStr;
      }

public int compareTo(AltString altStr2) {
      if (this.internalStr.length() < altStr2.internalStr.length()) {
          return -1;
      } else if (this.internalStr.length() > altStr2.internalStr.length()) {
          return 1;
      } else {
          int idx = 0;
          while (this.internalStr.charAt(idx) != altStr2.internalStr.charAt(idx)) {
              if (this.internalStr.charAt(idx) < altStr2.internalStr.charAt(idx)) {
                  return -1;
              }else if (this.internalStr.charAt(idx) > altStr2.internalStr.charAt(idx)) {
                  return 1;
              } else {
                  idx += 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // some test code for the AltString class
        String [] list = {"fortran", "java", "perl", "python", "php", "javascrip", "c", "c++", "c#", "ruby"};
        AltString [] alist = new AltString[list.length];
        for (int i=0; i<alist.length; i++) {
          alist[i] = new AltString(list[i]);
        }

        Arrays.sort(list);
        Arrays.sort(alist);
        System.out.println("String sort:");
        for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
          System.out.println(list[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("\nAltString sort:");
        for (int i=0; i<alist.length; i++) {
          System.out.println(alist[i]);
        }
      }
```

The part I am must stuck on is comparing the strings lexicographically.  Currently, I have my code setup so that I enter a while-loop and compare each char.

My question is, is this the most efficient way to do this, or is there a better way to compare each string lexicographically in the cases where the strings are the same length?

Comment: You do know lexicographic sorting is the default sorting of a String?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: @OmarN Tunaki means that in the `else` bit you can just do `return this.internalStr.compareTo(altStr2.internalStr);`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington, I thought about doing that, but wouldn't that be recursion at that point?

Comment: @OmarN No, unless `internalStr` is an `AltString`. We are all assuming it's a `String`, but you don't actually say that...

Comment: [See the compareTo method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String))

Comment: @OmarN - What is an AltString ? can we see rest of code?

Comment: @PaulBoddington, understood.  I added the rest of the code.

Comment: In addition to using String.compareTo(), you should also compare the lengths with Integer.compare().

Comment: `while ==` . Also **[java.text.Normalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html)** could be useful as one Unicode text could be written as different Strings. `ĉ` as one code point or two: `c` plus a zero-length `^`. The second form is nicer for sorting,

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone.  I guess the main question here is, does adding `return this.internalStr.compareTo(altStr2.internalStr);` after the `else` count as recursion in this case?  I thought that it did, and so that is why I used the while-loop instead.

Comment: @OmarN No it is not recursion. Recursion is when you call a method from inside itself. You are not doing that. `String.compareTo` is a different method from `AltString.compareTo`. They just happen to have the same name.

Comment: @PaulBoddington, thanks Paul.  If you add that as the answer, I will go ahead and accept it.  Thanks again.

Comment: @OmarN Done. I've made it a community wiki as it's really Tunaki and JB Nizet's answer, not mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the suggestions of Tunaki and JB Nizet, you can use `Integer.compare` and `String.compareTo`. Using `String.compareTo` does not count as recursion. Recursion is when you call a method from itself, but `String.compareTo` is a different method from `AltString.compareTo`.

```
public int compareTo(AltString altStr2) {
    int temp = Integer.compare(this.internalStr.length(), altStr2.internalStr.length());
    return temp != 0 ? temp : this.internalStr.compareTo(altStr2.internalStr);  
}
```